# Django: "django.http.request.RawPostDataException: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I keep getting an error every time I try to log this user in. Here are the relevant tracebacks:

```
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'body'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
raise RawPostDataException("You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream")
django.http.request.RawPostDataException: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream
```

This is inside my views.py:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def login(request):

    email = request.POST['email']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request)
        print("Breakpoint")
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    print('something went wrong')
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you're having conflicts in function names.

You probably have imported `auth.login` as

```
from django.contrib.auth import login
```

At the same time, your login view is named `login`. Hence the conflict.

Try changing import to

```
from django.contrib import auth
```

and then modify `login` view as:

```
if user is not None:
    auth.login(request)
```

Comment: You are my hero. Yeah, I've ran into a couple problems like that previously so I had to import the module.